# Calculate Determinant of Upper Triangular Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the determinant of upper triangular matrices (where $a_{ij}=0$ when $i>j$).

I am not sure how to calculate this using the definition of a determinant. It is the bit with the permutations  '$σ$' that doesn't make any sense.

If someone could provide the solution to this problem with an explanation of the permutations $( σ)$ it would help very much.

$$\det (A) = \sum\limits_{\sigma  \in {S_n}} {{\mathop{\rm sgn}} (\sigma ){a_{\sigma (1),1}}...{a_{\sigma (n),n}}} $$

Comment: What's your definition of determinant? There are several equivalent ones out there and in order to help, it might be useful to know this particular information. Apart from that, the answer should be that the determinant is the product of diagonal entries ($a_{ii}$).

Comment: det(A)=Σ(for σ ϵ Sn) of sgn(σ)a(σ(1),1)..........a(σ(n),n)

Answer (score 3):

We have for an $\;n\times n\;$ matrix $\;A\;$ :

$$\det A:=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} Syg(\sigma)\cdot\,a_{1\sigma(1)}\cdot a_{2\sigma(2)}\cdot\ldots\cdot a_{n\sigma(n)}$$

Now, note that

$$\sigma\neq id.:=\text{identity permutation}\implies \exists\,1\le i<j\le n\;\;s.t.\;\;\sigma(i)<i\;\text{(why??)}\implies a_{i\sigma(i)}$$

is an element **under** the main diagonal, and thus...

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of an upper diagonal matrix is the product of the entries on the diagonal. Use expansion along the first column to get $a_{1,1} * \text{ determinant with first row and column removed}$, and repeatedly expand along the first column.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ then

$$\det A=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\epsilon(\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^n a_{k\sigma(k)}$$
now for every permutation $\sigma\ne\operatorname{id}$  there's $k\in\{1,\ldots n\}$ such that $k>\sigma(k)$ so $a_{k\sigma(k)}=0$ hence we see that
$$\det A=\epsilon(\operatorname{id})\prod_{k=1}^n a_{k\operatorname{id}(k)}=\prod_{k=1}^n a_{kk}$$